# After updating cordova unable to build ios / android platform

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have update cordova to a newer version and after that i am not able to build any platform.
I have try to build a new project (`phonegap create ios_222`) and after that - `cordova platform add ios` and it gives me the following error:

> Unable to fetch platform ios: Error: EACCES, open
>   '/Users/admin/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/15c23c5a-cordova-ios-3-6-3.lock'

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue with (if 'admin' is your user):

```
sudo chmod -R admin /Users/admin/.cordova/lib/npm_cache
```

Hope that helps